# In Java using Exceptions specifically creating own exception how do I properly use the try, catch, finally command?

Tags: java, exception

I was tasked with creating an age program that when  a user enters their name and age and the program checks to see the age is between 0 and 125. If not, the program shows an error code (use Exception Class). 
My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
class InvalidAgeException extends Exception
{
public InvalidAgeException()
{
super("The Age you've entered is not valid");
}
}
class age3
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
try
{
int x, y;
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your name?");
String userInputName = userInputScanner.nextLine();
System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + userInputName +"!");
System.out.println("How old are you?");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
x = in.nextInt();
y = 125;
if (x<y)
System.out.println("Correct.Your age is less than 125");
else
System.out.println("Not Possible");
}
}
}
catch(InvalidAgeException e)
{
System.println("Invalid age error"+ e);
}
finally
{
System.out.println("Execution Completed")
}
```

Basically I made my statement that if false it should display a message saying they are wrong and also that at the end there should be an exception that shows simply that the person made an error.

These are my errors that I got:

3 errors

```
Mishas-MBP:desktop mishashtapov$ javac age3.java
age3.java:14: error: 'try' without 'catch', 'finally' or resource    declarations
try
^
age3.java:32: error: class, interface, or enum expected
catch(InvalidAgeException e)
^
age3.java:35: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
3 errors
```

**So my question is how do I properly use the try, catch, finally methods so it displays the exception???
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.**

*I used this outline that was on my online course:*

Exception Handling
Creating a User-defined Exception
In Java, it’s possible to create your own exception rather than using the predefined exceptions. Creating your own exception is creating a user defined exception. Now look at the exception created based on age calculation.
You are asked to check the age of the user when they enter their age in a program. As you know, the age-range of a person is limited: say 0 (birth) to 125. In writing the program, you specify this range so that if a user gives a number which is outside this range, the program could show an error message to the user.
In this case, you have to create your own exception. Look at the steps in the code below that defines the creation of a new exception.

```
Class InvalidAgeException extends Exception
{
public InvalidAgeException()
{
super("The Age you've entered is not valid");
}
}
class TestException
{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
try
{
     //Your Code Here
}
catch(InvalidAgeException ae)
{
System.println(“Your Exception”);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Mind to format your code please.

Comment: I see multiple closing curly braces before catch block starts. Make sure your catch block comes after the try ends. Also you made a typo "System.println" instead of "System.out.println" inside catch.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fix the syntax errors.

`catch` and `finally` should follow the try block's closing curly brace. Also, it should be `System.out.println` rather than `System.println`. And, your exception should be created and thrown in your logic.

You code should be

```
try {
     int x, y;
     Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("What is your name?");
     String userInputName = userInputScanner.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + userInputName + "!");
     System.out.println("How old are you?");
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     x = in.nextInt();
     y = 125;
     if (x < y)
         System.out.println("Correct.Your age is less than 125");
     else {
         throw new InvalidAgeException("Not Possible");
     }
} catch (InvalidAgeException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid age error" + e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Execution Completed")
}
```

For how to use Exceptions. I think Oracle's document would be a good place to look at. See [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to throw your custom exception when your age check fails. That will cause the exception to be caught in catch clause and to print the error. Something like :

```
    if (x<y)
System.out.println("Correct.Your age is less than 125");
else {
System.out.println("Not Possible");
//throw your exception here:
throw new InvalidAgeException();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you had some syntax errors.
`try`, `catch` and `finally` should follow each other. Also, it should be `System.out.println` instead of `System.println` in your catch.

Now the exception, you don't need a second class for your exception, just use `Exception e`, inbetween the brackets for the `catch`.

The following worked for me:

```
public class age3{

    public static void main(String arg[]){

        try{
            int x, y;
            Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What is your name?");
            String userInputName = userInputScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Nice to meet you " + userInputName +"!");
            System.out.println("How old are you?");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            x = in.nextInt();
            y = 125;
            if (x<y)
            System.out.println("Correct.Your age is less than 125");
            else
            System.out.println("Not Possible");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Invalid age error" + e);
        }finally{
            System.out.println("Execution Completed");
        }

    }
}
```

PS: try coding a bit neater next time, it is easier to read for both yourself and others :P

Comment: @KeqiangLi When I see the same mistake as you, it doesn't mean I am copying you, every decent programmer would have noticed those errors.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked and now I understand how catch finally work. But what is the purpose of using throw?

Comment: @Reshun : I don't think your answer is mentioning anything new here then. It appears you almost copied everything from the other answer.

Comment: @ShashankKadne Wow, so because it took me some time to get Eclipse open and test some things and was a bit later than means I copied him?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point of mentioning the same thing if you already see that as an answer from another user? I believe now you will start answering other questions too which are answered before? If you would have made a different point while answering, I would have understood!